# Why did Lord Shiva fight with Lord Vishnu?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, avatars, harivamsa

What were the reason(s) behind the fight between Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu? I think the Harivamsa Parva of the Mahabharata narrates this incident.

The [story](http://www.startv.in/episodes/mahadev-and-lord-vishnu-fight-with-each-other/44126) goes like this:

> Mahadev makes Goddess Lakshmi realise that she has done a mistake by
>   suspecting Lord Vishnu. Goddess Lakshmi pleads with Mahadev to bring
>   Lord Vishnu back. Mahadev goes to the Patal Lok in Vrishabh’s disguise
>   to bring Lord Vishnu back. Mahadev and Lord Vishnu fight with each
>   other. 
>   Their fight continues for years. Ganesha promises Parvati to
>   put an end to Mahadev and Lord Vishnu’s fight. Lord Brahma becomes
>   worried as Lord Vishnu attacks Mahadev with Narayana Astra.

What is the actual story?

Comment: If you have this much of the story, then probably you have the rest too. Why do you ask, then?

Comment: @ Dharmaputhiran - I don't think this is a full story. That's why I'm asked this question....

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are multiple incidents you could be referring to:.

1. The story depicted in the TV serial you linked to is (loosely) based on a story told in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/7u3C) from the Shatarudra Samhita of the Shiva Purana, about a battle between Vishnu and Shiva's incarnation Vrishabha the bull, AKA Vrishesha.

   Most accounts of Churning of the Ocean end with Vishnu tricking the Asuras by turning into Mohini, and then the gods defeating the Asuras (demons) in battle after drinking the Amrita (nectar of immortality).  But the Shiva Purana tells a modified version of the story, where a bunch of beautiful Apsaras (nymphs) are born out of stray drops of Amrita, and the Asuras enchanted by their beauty kidnap them and take them to Patalaloka (the underworld).  Then the battle between the gods and the Asuras take place, and Vishnu in the course of fighting the Asuras chases them all the way to Patalaloka.  But then after he defeats them, he sees the beautiful Apsaras, and struck by the arrow of Kama (the god of love) he becomes enamoured of them.  So he fathers a bunch of children with them, and those sons soon becomes a menace to the three worlds:

   > Vishnu begot of them sons of great exploits and valour, experts in various kinds of warfare, shaking the entire earth.  Those sons of Vishnu of great strength and valour wrought great havoc both in heaven and earth causing misery to all.  On seeing the geat harm done to the worlds the gods and the sages approached Brahma and informed him of this after bowing to him.

   Then Brahma goes to Shiva, informing of him of the mayhem caused by the sons of Vishnu, and asks Shiva to make Vishnu leave Patalaloka and stop his dalliances with those Apsaras.  So Shiva turns into Vrishabha the bull and goes into Patalaloka, killing Vishnu's sons and fighting Vishnu:

   > Then  bellowing  in  the  form of  a  Bull,  [Shiva] the  Pinaka-bearing  lord  entered  the  crevice  and  shouted  terribly.  At  his  bellowing  sound,  cities  and  towns  crumbled down  and  all  the  citizens  trembled.  Then  the  bull  attacked  Vishnu's sons  wielding  their bows  for  fighting,  deluded  by  Siva's  Maya and  proud  of their  great  strength  and  exploit....  [T]he  sons  of  Vishnu became  furious.  Those  heroes  roared  loudly  and  rushed  against  Siva.  Rudra  in  that  form  of  a  bull  was  furious  at  those sons of  Vishnu  who  rushed  at  him.  He  kicked  them  with his  hoofs  and  tore  them  with  his  horns.  When  their  limbs  were  split  by  Rudra,  they  swooned  and  lost  their  lives.  They  were  immediately  destroyed.
   >
   > When  they  were  killed  Vishnu  the  foremost  of  the strong  came  out  shouting  loudly  and  hastened  towards  Siva.  On  seeing  Siva  in  the  form of a bull going along after killing  his  sons,  Vishnu  hit  him  with  divine arrows and
   >   missiles. Then  the  infuriated  Siva,  the  highly  powerful  one in  the  form  of  a  bull  stood  like  a  mountain  and  caught hold  of  all  those  missiles  of  Vishnu.  O  sage,  shouting  furiously,  lord  Siva  in  the  form of a  bull  shook  the  three  worlds  terribly.  The  lord  leaped  up  suddenly  and  kicked  the  infuriated  Vishnu who  was  deluded  and  could  not  realise  him. The  lard  then  tore  him  with  his  horns.  Unable  to  bear  the  onslaught, Vishnu  deluded  by Maya  was  exhausted  and  utterly  shattered.

   So Vishnu finally snaps out of the Maya and realizes that the bull is Shiva.  Embarrassed that he didn't recognize Shiva sooner, Vishnu leaves his Sudarshana Chakra (discus weapon) in Patalaloka and returns to Lakshmi, and Shiva provides him with a new Sudarshana Chakra, even more powerful than the old one.  (The Sudarshana Chakra was anyway provided by Shiva, as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2181/36).)

   I should make clear that this story is probably not authentic, but rather a later interpolation to the Shiva Purana, because no story remotely like this is found in any other Puranas or other Hindu scriptures.  And there are no other scriptures that mention Vishnu begetting children with women other than his wives.  (But there are references to Vishnu having children with Lakshmi in the Sri Sukta of the Rig Veda Khilani, as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/868/36).)
2. You mentioned the Harivamsa, but story above doesn't occur in the Harivamsa.  The Harivamsa does describe, however, a battle between Shiva and Vishnu's incarnation Krishna, in [this chapter](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_124.html) and [this chapter](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_125.html) of the Vishnu Parva.  (It's also described in [this chapter](http://vedabase.com/en/sb/10/63/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam.)

   Krishna's grandson Aniruddha was once kidnapped by the demon Bana (son of Mahabali), who had captured Aniruddha after he discovered that his daughter Usha and Aniruddha were in love.  So Krishna came with Balarama and the armies of Dwaraka to defeat Bana and rescue his grandson.  They soon defeated Bana's armies, so Shiva and his Gana army came to Bana's aid, since Bana was a great devotee of Shiva.  Thus begin an epic battle between Krishna and Shiva, where they launched many powerful Astras (magical weapons) at one another.  The battle became so destructive, with Krishna winning, that Bhumidevi the goddess of the Earth worried that the Earth wouldn't survive it, so she asked Brahma to put an end to it.  Brahma approached Shiva and [asked him](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_125.html) to stop fighting:

   > The lord Brahma looked at Rudra (Shiva) and spoke the following words: "The destruction of great demons has started now (with your consent). Then why are you protecting them?  O the one with great arms! I do not like your fighting with Krishna. Also you are not understanding Krishna with your intellect. Your soul is divided in two parts (of which one is Krishna)."  When he was advised thus by Brahma, the lord (Shiva), the lord who does not have any decline, entered his (own) body by yoga and visualized the entire three worlds along with all the moving and fixed beings.  Then Rudra (Shiva) who is born from a single source, realized his own soul as the soul of Krishna (Brahma - the ultimate soul).

   So Shiva realized that Krishna was none other than Vishnu, who is Paramatma the supreme soul and thus undefeatable, so he surrendered.  In case you're wondering, Krishna was successful in defeating Bana and rescued Aniruddha, but he spared Bana's life because Bana was the great-grandson of Vishnu's great devotee Prahlada.  And Bana too became friendly with Krishna.  So Aniruddha married Bana's daughter Usha and everyone went back to Dwaraka.
3. Strictly speaking neither of the above stories actually describe a battle between Vishnu and Shiva; the first story is about a battle between Vishnu and Shiva's incarnation Vrishabha, and the second story is about a battle between Shiva and Vishnu's incarnation Krishna.  As far as I'm aware, the only battle between Vishnu and Shiva themselves is the one [described by Parashurama](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/bala/sarga75/bala_75_frame.htm) in the Bala Kanda of the Ramayana, and Vishnu won it merely by saying "hum":

   > Once, all the gods were asking the Grandparent, Brahma, as to who is powerful and who is less powerful among the blue-throated Shiva and Vishnu, but the Grandparent Brahma on inferring the intent of gods started to create adversity among those two, Shiva and Vishnu, for the Grandparent is the best adherer of truthfulness, as truth cannot be demonstrated on hearsay evidence.  Owing to their animosity then occurred a fierce and hair-raising war among Shiva and Vishnu, as each aspired victory for himself. By the 'hum' sound of Vishnu that ruinously overpowering longbow of Shiva is broken, and the triple-eyed God, Mahadeva, is frozen.
   >
   > Then gods along with the assemblages of sages and celestial carana-s have come together and appealed to those two for appeasement in the matter of wielding authority, and then those two superior gods, Shiva and Vishnu, went into a state of amity. On seeing the bow of Shiva rendered inert by the mettlesomeness of Vishnu, from then on **the gods along with the assemblages of sages deemed Vishnu to be the paramount**.

   In case you're wondering, Shiva's bow is the same one that was later broken by Vishnu's incarnation Rama to win Sita's hand in marriage.

On a side note, there is also a story of a battle between Vishnu's incarnation Narasimha, Shiva's incarnation Sharabha, and Vishnu's incarnation Gandhabherunda, which I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/191/36), but I haven't found a full scriptural basis for that story yet.

Comment: @KiranRS So which of the three stories were you thinking of?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.What I was looking for the answer  exactly in your first example.

Comment: You have mentioned Rishabha as an avatar of Lord Shiva. I have asked a question on this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9049/was-rishabha-the-first-tirthankar-of-jainism-an-incarnation-of-lord-vishnu-or

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Actually, I think incident 1 is the least authentic - it's not mentioned in any Hindu scripture other than that one chapter of the Shiva Purana, and it's the only place in Hindu scripture that describes Vishnu having children with anyone other than his wives.  So I think it's clearly an interpolation.  The other two stories are well-established in Hindu scripture.

Comment: Please educate me here. In incident #3, it says: _By the 'hum' sound of Vishnu that ruinously overpowering longbow of Shiva is **broken**_ and in the following comment you say: _Shiva's bow is the **same one that was later broken** by Vishnu's incarnation Rama_. How can the same bow be broken twice? Was it "fixed" by someone?

Comment: @sv. That's just a translation issue.  The original Sanskrit doesn't say broken, it says jrimbhitam, which means yawned or fatigued, i.e. rendered motionless.  But yes, it is the same bow that Rama broke; after Vishnu and Shiva's conflict, the bow was passed down among the kings of Mithila until Janaka acquired it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that makes sense. It does say later on, _On seeing the **bow of Shiva rendered inert**_.

Comment: @sv. Yeah, I think what basically happened is that the bowstring completely froze, so that it wouldn't fire the arrow.

Comment: It is possible that Vishnu got children with someone other than his wives. The first incident says he got deluded. I think that may just be a part of his leela.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I'm just saying there's no other scripture that mentions Vishnu having children with women other than his wives, and there's no other scriptures that mention this story, so that's one of the things that suggests that it's an interpolation.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I don't know what you mean by the scholars of Hastinapura, but generally I operate according to the principle that if something is mentioned in multiple scriptures, it is more likely to be authentic than something that is only mentioned in one scripture.  So that would lead me to accept the Yugas figures and reject the Vrishabha story.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria First of all, it is not true that the majority of Hindus are Advaitins.  Second of all, I didn't say that I accept whatever a lot of people believe, I said I tend to accept something if a lot of scriptures say it.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, I reject the notion that almost every realized soul is an Advaitin, but we just have a fundamental disagreement about who is and isn't realized.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, you do have a disagreement with me, because I don't think that :-) But we'll just have to agree to disagree on that.

Comment: No, I don't have any disagreement with you. You think Advaitins are not realized but I agree that many Vaishnavas are realized. I know that those who go out in search of God with sincere effort, God himself will show the path.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, we do disagree about the state of Advaitins, but in any case I agree with your last statement about those who seek.

Answer (score 2):

First, to deal with the [Vrishbha incident](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226418.html#note-t-88805), the first thing to realise is that the form of Vishnu involved is Mohinī, since the text starts talking about her with no sign of stopping. While a later verse is usually translated as her having sex with the damsels, it actually [uses the instrumental case](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-sanskrit/d/doc397106.html). Thus, it makes sense for Mohinī to be possessing the damsels instead.

> 33. Viṣṇu, the most excellent of those who wield Māyā assuming the form of a woman Mohinī deluded the Asuras and made the gods drink it.

> Fascinated by the Cupid’s arrows Viṣṇu attained highest pleasure only there. He began to indulge in sexual dalliance with those women of exquisite beauty.

This makes sense with the story, as it explains why takes longer to recognize Shiva, as she could be sleeping letting the possessed damsels work mostly to themselves. Also, the story clearly has Mohinī's Maya and Shiva's Maya be the same thing.

> 33. Viṣṇu, the most excellent of those who wield Māyā assuming the form of a woman Mohinī deluded the Asuras and made the gods drink it.
> 34. The leading Daityas approached her and said—“Make us drink this nectar. Let there be no break in the lines.”
> 35. All those Daityas and Dānavas deluded by Śiva’s Māyā said thus and gave the nectar to Viṣṇu in disguise.

---

Both for that incident and more generally, not all forms of Vishnu are supreme. Some are partial, for example, [Prithu](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp048.htm)

> Brahmá recognised a **portion of that divinity** in Prithu

This is also recorded in his presumably different birth in the [Devi Bhagavatam](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk07ch09.htm)

> Kâkutstha had the son Prithu, of mighty prowess. Prithu was the **part incarnation personified of Visnu**, and worshipper of the feet of the Supreme S'akti

Thus, it was probably one of them, especially all the Puranas not labeled Sattva in the Padma Purana tend to be ambiguous of which incarnation they are talking about.

As a side note, while we cannot say for sure Prithu has flaws (or close to flaws), there is the possibility he is the same as the Vasu Prithu, who steals a cow. It is mentioned in the [Devi Bhagavatam](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk02ch03.htm) and [Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01100.htm)

> Prithu and others, one Vasu Dyau's wife seeing Nandini, the sacrificial cow (Kâmadhenu) of Vas'istha asked her husband :-- “Whose is this excellent cow that I see?  Vasu then replied as follows :-- “ O Beautiful one! This is Vas'istha's cow. Whoever, be he a man or woman drinks her milk gets his longevity extended to ten thousand years and his youth never ends.” Hearing this, the Vasu's wife said :-- “There is a very beautiful comrade (Sakhî) of mine, the daughter of the Rajarsî-Us'îna in the world, of auspicious qualities. O Mahâbhâga! Kindly bring to me from Vas'istha's hermitage that auspicious sacrificial milch cow Nandini together with her calf that yields all desires; my Sakhî will then drink her milk and be thereby free from disease, old age and become the chief amongst all mankind. Hearing thus, his wife's word, the Vasu Dyau, though sinless, **stole away together with Prithu** and the other Vasus the cow Nandini in utter defiance to the self-controlled Muni Vas'istha. When the cow Nandini had been stolen, the great ascetic Vas'istha came quickly to the hermitage with abundance of fruits.

> On hearing these words of his wife, Dyu, moved by the desire of humouring her, **stole that cow, aided by his brothers Prithu and the others**. Indeed, Dyu, commanded by his lotus-eyed wife, did her bidding, forgetting at the moment the high ascetic merits of the Rishi who owned her. He did not think at the time that he was going to fall by committing the sin of stealing the cow.

As another side note I think all the partial incarnations are actually incarnations of Indra, who is a partial incarnation of Vishnu. The only reason they are listed as incarnations of Rudra or Vishnu is the authors know humans are not going to pay attention unless the supreme deity (or a supreme goal) is involved.