# The incarnations of Vishnu who used the Sharanga

Tags: vishnu, krishna, rama, vishnu-sahasranama

Vishnu's celestial bow is the Sharanga and I am aware that lord Rama and used it and is known as Kodandapani too, Are there any other incarnations of Vishnu who used the Sharanga other than Rama and Krishna

Vishnu Sahasranama also mentions a name

> maheṣvāsaḥ - He who wields Sharanga

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3658/how-did-krishna-get-vishnus-sharanga-bow?rq=1
This question mentions Parashurama, the sixth Avatar of Lord Vishnu possessing the Sharanga bow too.

Comment: Ohh, Are there other incarnations?

Comment: No Sir i did some more digging up but could not find any other Avatar possessing it.