# Bull in front of Lord Shiva's shrine is Nandi or Rishaba?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam, nandi

I saw an online discussion where a learned commentator shared that the bull in front of Shiva Linga is Rishaba and not Nandhi and associating the bull with Nandi is a general misunderstanding among Hindus. Is this true? What is the story associated with the Rishaba connection?

Comment: Are you refering to jain Tirthankara Rishabha? if yes then there is no hindu Scripture proof for that. If you just want to know if nandi is bull then you may find an answer here http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6980/was-nandi-really-a-bull

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the other question. This question is whether the bull in front of Shiva shrines is Rishaba or not.

Comment: I guess the Tirthankara Rishaba is the only Rishaba?

Comment: I think the answer by Keshav Srinivasan is Satisfactory since he has quoted Shiva purana and Anushasan Parva of Mahabharta to prove his point that bull and nandi are different.