# Can a Vaishnava saint give Shakti mantra mantra initiation to any one or vice versa?

Tags: mantras, guru, tantra

According to the Mantrayogasamhita, different people with different mental inclinations should have different deities as Ishta. Can a Vaishnava Guru give initiation by Shakti mantra or a Shaakta Guru for Vishnu/Krishna/Gopala mantra?

Comment: You can see my answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22986/can-vaishnavas-join-the-natha-sampradaya/22989#22989

Comment: @Rickross thanks, but i think the law differs for siddha mantra or siddha guru

Comment: Yes it is said if Siddha Guru is giving mantra or if mantra itself is Siddha no need to consider any other factors..

Comment: @Rickross so pl write the answer for this also:)

Comment: I don't hv more verses right now .. I will hv to chk

Comment: Flood of questions

Comment: @RakeshJoshi yes because i am leavingmsoon

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee many misconceptions to be cleared

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee yours..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22989/4732), a Shakta should get a Shakta Guru and same for a Vaishnava.

But when a Siddha Guru is giving Mantra the disciple should not consider which Mantra it is.

Omkarnath was a Vaishnava saint. His Sampradaya was Ramanandi. But he gave Dikshas of various other deity Mantras too.

Quoting from their [website](http://jaigurusampradaya.org/spiritual_lineage.php):

> The Ramananda sect worships only Lord Ram. Thakur's Istadev was Ram,
>   **but still, He liberalised the Diksha Parampara of His sampraday, and gave the Mantras of all Deities, as per the adhikara, background,
>   spiritual inclination of individual devotees.** Every Form of Lord is
>   inseparable from Lord Ram, and Thakur's improvisation was to
>   supplement the usual Ramanandiya customs. Even Thakur's guru
>   [Dasarathidev], gave the Mantras of 5 deities, ie- [person in whose
>   body SKY element is more should recieve Vishnu mantra , in the same
>   way for FIRE element Shakti Mantra , for EARTH element Shiva Mantra ,
>   for AIR element Surya mantra & for WATER element Ganesh Mantra .]

So, there seems to be no problem if the Guru is Adhikari (competent) and I think this competency comes from Krama Dikshas, Purna Abhisekhas.