# Where in the Narada Purana is the prophecy of Ramanujacharya?

Tags: puranas, adisesha

As I discuss in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3039/36), the Sri Vaishnava sect of Hinduism (of which I'm a member) was founded by Nathamuni, based on the beliefs and principles embodied in the poems of the Alwars, a group of 12 ancient Vaishnava saints who lived in Tamil Nadu and are famous for their poetry in praise of Vishnu.  But at the time of Nathamuni, Sri Vaishnavism was just a small cult in the town of Sri Rangam in Tamil Nadu.  As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2835/36), Sri Vaishnavism only became a major sect of Hinduism after the time of Ramanujacharya, by far the most famous Sri Vaishnava Acharya.

According to Sri Vaishnavism, Ramanujacharya was an incarnation of Adiseshan and a reincarnation of Balarama.  In [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/4023/36), I discuss numerous Hindu scriptures that mention Ramanujacharya.  But there is one mention of him that I'm trying to track down.  In his book "The Life and Teachings of Sri Ramanujacharya",  C. R. Sreenivasa Ayyangar [gives a quote](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zn4szeEn23IC&lpg=PA178&ots=dGbasgpmcE&dq=%22golden%20lives%20of%20the%20east%22&pg=PA44#v=onepage&q&f=false) from the Narada Purana which prophesies the birth of Ramanujacharya.

> His primal manifestation was as Ananta [Adiseshan]; his second as Lakshmana, the younger brother of Rama; his third as Balabhadra the elder brother of Krishna; and once again he will come down on Earth in the Kali Yuga.

My question is, where in the Narada Purana is this quote found?  The book says it's from the Yadavachala Mahatmya of the Narada Purana, and I've heard other people saying the quote comes from the Yadavagiri Mahatmya of the Narada Purana.  Either way, the phrase means "Greatness of the Yadava mountain", a hill in Melukote, Tamil Nadu which is the site of the famous [Cheluvanarayana Swami Vishnu Temple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheluvanarayana_Swamy_Temple).

But I can't find a section with that name in the Narada Purana.  You can read the table of contents to the Narada Purana [here](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/narada-purana-5-volumes-IDE885/).  And you can read the Narada Purana via DSpace, the digital repository of the West Bengal Public Library Network; here are links to all five volumes (in English):

- [Volume 1](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12945)
- [Volume 2](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/20659)
- [Volume 3](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/21516)
- [Volume 4](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12976)
- [Volume 5](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/handle/10689/12978)

So which of these volumes has the Yadavachala Mahatmya?  And does anyone know specifically where the quote I'm lookingg for is?

Comment: I know from my sravanam of Hindu discourses that Patanjali who wrote Yoga Sutras was an incarnation of Adisesha.

Comment: I did not find link in Narada Purana either, but please read [this post](http://hindudharmaforums.com/archive/index.php/t-2247.html) which claims that Ramanujacharya's avatar is indicated in Padma Purana. Hope this helps you.