# What is the purpose of Balarama's avatara?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, balarama

Lord Vishnu, through his avatars, teaches us how to live. I was wondering what is the purpose of Krishna's elder brother Balarama. Also, it seems very odd from the other avatars of Vishnu, because each of the other avatars was born in a different yuga.

So what is the purpose of the Balarama avatara? And why did Vishnu decide to take two avatars in the same yuga?

Comment: Thanks iammilind. Since balarama is not a direct avatar of Lord Vishnu can that be counted as one of the ten avatar of Vishnu?  I have heard people say that Buddha is an avatar of Lord vishnu. How much truth is in it ?

Comment: Actually some people say and even I too believe that Vishnu's avataras are not limited to number like 10 or something. Vishnu's constantly incarnating as and when required. Look at this post: "[What are the exact ten avatars of Vishnu?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/927/what-are-the-exact-ten-avatars-of-vishnu)

Comment: I strongly recommend you to watch this video on youtube, this is not for religious view but you will be clear about all the incarnation of God after watching this video. Please watch this video. I think this video will explain everything better than any other. [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZYiH5snMYU).

Comment: @Parasuraman See my answer here for why Balarama is considered an incarnation of Vishnu: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2820/36

Comment: @Parasuraman - It is not unique that both Balarama and Krishna were born in same Yuga. Even Krishna Dwaipayana alias Vyasa who also amsa avatara of Vishnu was born during Dwapara. We need not be surprised, as it is will of the Lord.

Comment: Balarama was also involved in killing host of Rakshashas. Please read Hari Vamsa, Bhagavatham. Balaraama killed lakhs and lakhs of Asuras who supported Jarasandha and his friends. Balaraama seized Jarasandha and was about to kill him, when akashhvani and Krishna stopped him, so that Jarasandha can recoup and bring more asuras to fight thereby making it easy fir Balarama and Krishna to eliminate them.

Comment: @Krishna What scripture says the Akashvanj stopped him?  I just thought Krishna stopped him.

Comment: @Keshav - I think  it is in Hari Vamsa, i am not sure...Even, Madhva in Mahabharata tatparya nirnaya seem to comment on this incident saying Aksshavani stopped Balarama from slaying Jarasandha saying that he is not destined to die at his hands. Yes, some scriptures say that Krishna stopped him...

Comment: @Krishna OK, I found it: "Then the voice of the witness of the world, was heard in the sky: 'O rAma (balarAma)! O One who respect others! (jarAsaMdha) is not to be killed by you. You need not lament. Ihave foreseen his death. Hence control yourself. In a short time, the lord of magadha (jarAsaMdha) will lose his life.'" http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_043.html

Comment: Balarama avatar has not been given much coverage in the Mahabharata epic, and he also did not have the "Yogic Capacity" of Sri Krishna to stay "unruffled" on a battlefield like Kurukshetra, when mystical weapons would fly all over the battlefield{and many did hit Sri Krishna and he stayed unruffled}.So, from that angle, the Balarama avatar of God Vishnu, had only other roles to perform, like teaching mace science to Bhima and Duryodhana, going on pilgrimage,,administrative work related toYadu dynasty etc..

Comment: Krishna taunts him when he undertook pilgrimages to avoid action when Mahabharat war was in full swing,

Answer (score 1):

Namaste

Avatar purush when they take birth, they bring their supplementary ecosystem also.  In Ramayana, brother Laxmana is shown suspicious or apprehensive of schemy step mother Kaikeyi & her son Bharat.  Eldest brother Lord Rama always overrides such fears and being devoted brother, Laxmana obeyed it, but always nursed grouse if he had been elder brother, he would have done this and avoided that....etc..
To that statement, Lord Rama said that opportunity would be coming in next avatar rebirth i.e. Lord Krishna' elder brother Balarama.
In both cases, he had to either take orders from elder brother who had better understanding of the nature laws and rules, while in subsequent role, Lord Krishna displayed superior logic and compliance to the eternal destiny, so Balarama had no choice but to accept it.
So to say Balarama is an avatar (smaller / lesser), is ok, to the extent of his relation with Lord Krishna
In contrast, Balarama (Mahabharata) had more of family life, which he voluntarily forgone to serve his elder brother during the exile (Ramayana)

Answer (score 1):

It is same as Krishna's purpose. To remove the burden of the world.

> ekonaviṁśe viṁśatime vṛṣṇiṣu prāpya janmanī rāma-kṛṣṇāv iti bhuvo
>   bhagavān aharad bharam
>
> In the nineteenth and twentieth incarnations, the Lord advented
>   Himself as Lord Balarāma and Lord Kṛṣṇa in the family of Vṛṣṇi [the
>   Yadu dynasty], **and by so doing He removed the burden of the world.** [SB 1.3.23](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/3/23/)

Vasudeva speaks to Krishna and Balarama.

> yuvāṁ na naḥ sutau sākṣāt pradhāna-puruṣeśvarau
>   bhū-bhāra-kṣatra-kṣapaṇa avatīrṇau tathāttha ha
>
> You are not our sons but the very Lords of both material nature and
>   its creator [Mahā-Viṣṇu]. **As You Yourself have told us, You have
>   descended to rid the earth of the rulers who are a heavy burden upon
>   her**. [SB 10.85.18](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/85/18/)