# When lord Krishna takes the form of Shreenathaji?

Tags: krishna, vaishnavism

There are different forms of lord Krishna described in *Shreemad Bhagwad Geeta* like

- Bal Krishna
- Purna Purushottam
- Ranchodrayji
- Giridhar Gopal
- Makhan Chor

... etc.

But I want to know that why and how lord Krishna takes the form of *Shreenathaji*.

Every *Vaishanva* follows the form of Shreenathaji with *Yamunaji* and *Maha Prabhuji*. So what is the story behind this?

Comment: I don't think you're using the word swarupa properly.  What are you trying to say?

Comment: I mean to say the different forms of Lord shree krishana

Comment: You should change swarupa to form in the rest of your post as well.  In any case, where in the Bhagavad Gita does Krishna talk about forms like Bala Krishna and so on?

Comment: The Srinathji idol just depicts Krishna as a child lifting up the Govardhana hill, as I discuss in this answer: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2950/36 Does that answer your question?

Comment: Googling gave this as first result: http://www.nathdwara.in/history.php