# What are the 30 avatars of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

I have an assignment that I need help finding the answer to. I cannot find the answer anywhere on the internet. I don't have the book for my class to help me.

Comment: Srimad Bhagavatham (Canto 1.3) speaks about 22 avatars of Vishnu- http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/3

Comment: Maybe I can help you.  What is the book that's used in your class?

Comment: There are scriturally mentioned either 22 or 24 *avataras* of Lord *Vishnu* or they are counted as innumerable . In any case there are no texts that explicitly  gives terms like "30 Avataras of Vishnu"

Answer (score 6):

Below are the 24 Avtaras of lord Vishnu. Out of which, 23 happened already. Kalki is said to be 24th Avtara in future.

1- श्री सनकादि मुनि (Shri Sankadi Muni) :

2- वराह अवतार (Varaha Avtar) :

3- नारद अवतार (Narad Avtar) :

4- नर-नारायण (Nar-Narayan Avtar) :

5- कपिल मुनि ( Kapil Avtar) :

6- दत्तात्रेय अवतार (Dattatraya Avtar) :

7-  यज्ञ ( Yagya Avatar) :

8- भगवान ऋषभदेव (Rishabh Avtar) :

9- आदिराज पृथु (Prithu Avtar) :

10- मत्स्य अवतार (Matsya Avtar) :

11- कूर्म अवतार (Kurm Avtar) :

12- भगवान धन्वन्तरि (Dhanwantari Avatar) :

13- मोहिनी अवतार (Mohini avatar) :

14- भगवान नृसिंह (Narsih Avatar) :

15- वामन अवतार (Vaman Avatar) :

16- हयग्रीव अवतार (Hayagreeva Avatar) :

17- श्रीहरि अवतार ( Shri Hari Avtar) :

18- परशुराम अवतार (Parshuram Avatar) :

19- महर्षि वेदव्यास ( Vyas Avatar) :

20- हंस अवतार (Hans Avatar) :

21- श्रीराम अवतार (Ram avatar) :

22- श्रीकृष्ण अवतार (Krishna Avatar) :

23- बुद्ध अवतार (Buddha Avatar) :

24- कल्कि अवतार (Kalki Avatar) :

Apart from those, [Shrinathji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrinathji) & [Swami Narayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swaminarayan) can also be considered as re-incarnations of lord Shri Krishna.

[24 Avtara of Vishnu with description](http://www.ajabgjab.com/2014/08/24-avatars-incarnations-of-lord-vishnu.html)

[24 Avtara of Vishnu with English desccription](http://avatarsofbrahmavishnumahesh.blogspot.in/2013/07/24-avatar-of-lord-vishnu.html)

Comment: Good collection. Perhaps *Shrinathji* & *Swami Narayana* can also be considered as Avatars. There is a famous story that, Swamy Narayana's parents were cursed by Ashwatthama that their son will not be able to possess any weapons; since he foresaw that it's going to be Krishna's incarnation.

Comment: was there any avatar of vishnu by name ADI PURUSHA avatar?

Comment: @AnilKumar yes this link describe   http://avatarsofbrahmavishnumahesh.blogspot.in/2013/07/24-avatar-of-lord-vishnu.html  Adi Purusha   Incarnation as the Pre-eminent man

Comment: @BhavinChhatrola i know that link. In fact i came to know about that avatar from that page. But i want to know whether it was mentioned in any of the puranas? Is that Adi Purusha Avatar is Lord Narayana , amsa of Vishnu who lives in Vaikunta?

Comment: Can you rearrange them by the order in which they happened? Because I think Matsya Avatar was the 1st incarnation.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria no, matsya avtara is first avtara when we talk about lord vishnu's Exact 10 avtara see here : http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/927/what-are-the-exact-ten-avatars-of-vishnu  and matsya is first avtar of current manavatar

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria  see here read this artical which avtara came first Matsya is fourth avtara http://www.veda.harekrsna.cz/encyclopedia/avatars.htm see also image here http://www.veda.harekrsna.cz/images/avataras.jpg

Comment: Rishabhdev is also the first tirthankar of Jainism. Rishabhdev attained enlightenment at Mount Kailash, the abode of Lord Shiva. Rishabh is also one name of Shiva. So how Rishabhdev is also linked to Lord Shiva, why he is also linked to Jainism and why he is also an avatar of Lord Vishnu?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria you should ask this question in this site or may be here the answer of your question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishabha_(Hinduism)  why he related to Vishnu & Shiva

Comment: @iammilind Srinathji isn't a separate incarnation; the Srinathji statue is just a statue of Krishna, as I discuss in my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2950/36 As far as Swaminarayan goes, pretty much only members of the Swaminarayan sect believe he's an incarnation, although the site some scriptures to support their view, like the Skanda Purana quote in my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6623/36

Answer (score 2):

1   Ajita (from Vishnu Purana)

2   Balarāma (from Bhāgavata Purāṇ)

3   Buddha (from Bhāgavata Purāṇ)

4   Dattatreya (from Bhāgavata Purāṇ)

5   Dhanvantari (from Bhāgavata Purāṇ)

6   Haṁsa (from Bhāgavata Purāṇ)

7   Hari (from Vishnu Purana)

8   Hayagreeva (from Bhāgavata Purāṇ)

9   Kalki

10  Kapila (from Bhāgavata Purāṇ)

11  Krishna

12  Krishna Dvaipāyana (28th Vyasa)

13  Kumāras (from Bhāgavata Purāṇ)

14  Kurma

15  Mánasa (from Vishnu Purana)

16  Mandhata (from Vayu Purana)

17  Matsya

18  Mohini

19  Nārada (from Bhāgavata Purāṇ)

20  Nārāyaṇa Rishi

21  Nrisimha

22  Parashurama

23  Pṛthu (from Bhāgavata Purāṇ)

24  Rama

25  Ṛṣabha (from Bhāgavata Purāṇ)

26  Satya (from Vishnu Purana)

27  Vaikuntha (from Vishnu Purana)

28  Vámana

29  Varaha

30  Yajna (from Vishnu Purana)