# Is it true that Vishnu has not only 10 avatars but 24?

Tags: mahabharata, vyasa

Today when I was reading a magazine I got to know from it that Lord Vishnu has total 24 avatars and his 21st avatar was guru Veda Vyas who wrote Mahabharata. Is that true as well that Veda vyasa is the person who divided or say separated all 3 major Granthas of Hindus?

And also as per wikipedia

> महाभारत के बारे में कहा जाता है कि इसे महर्षि वेदव्यास के गणेश को बोलकर लिखवाया था। वेदव्यास महाभारत के रचयिता ही नहीं, बल्कि उन घटनाओं के साक्षी भी रहे हैं, जो क्रमानुसार घटित हुई हैं।

Translation of above quote is

"*It is said about the Mahabharata that it was written by Maharishi Vedavesh Ganesh for speaking. Vedas not only have been the creators of the Mahabharata, but also have witnessed the events which have happened in sequence.*"

So why he is not mentioned anywhere in whole Mahabharata?

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19956/who-are-the-24-avataras-of-lord-vishnu-according-to-the-srimad-bhagavatam

Comment: Is your question no. of avatars or Vyasa mentioning himself as Vishnu avatar or Vyasa's name in Mahabharat? Because 24 avatars are not mentioned in Mahabharat. So, he can't mention himself as avatara. Also this is an English language site.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma No that is one short answer either that's true or not. and another is vedvayasa was not mentioned any of the things happened in Mahabharata that is what I am asking

Comment: @SwiftPushkar as mentioned in the question Vayasa is actually ved Vyasa? And isn't he 21st avatar of Vishnu ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who are the 24 avataras of Lord Vishnu according to the Srimad Bhagavatam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19956/who-are-the-24-avataras-of-lord-vishnu-according-to-the-srimad-bhagavatam), [Has Veda Vyasa seen Lord Krishna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8061/5212)  and [What are the 30 avatars of Vishnu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8903/5212)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar The question is not Vyasa mentioned in Mahabharata as an incarnation. It is just mentioned. Look at the Wikipedia quote. Which is covered in one of the duplicates I linked in the comment.  and Dictator, the quotes should be in English. If it's not there, provide translation for it.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I am asking why Veda is not mentioned in Mahabharata. Not the second one.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Now I need to find the translated version of it :/

Comment: @TheDictator ok , he is mentioned in MB several times.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar any reference of it ?

Comment: Vyasa appeared before karna , Duryodhana and Shakuni to stop them  from killing the pandavas , which were in forest for agyatvasa . - Vana Parva -  Chapters 7-9. - http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03007.htm  - Also chapter 259 from same parva .

Comment: @TheDictator Look through the duplicates I linked. All your questions are already asked and answered on site. Your question is a duplicate of several questions. Please try to ask only one question per post. You can just translate the quote into English. -1 because of many questions and Hindi quote.