# Did Vishnuswami write a commentary on the Brahma Sutras?

Tags: history, vedanta, vaishnavism, brahma-sutras, pushti-marga

As I discuss in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10174/36), Vishnu is said to have taught the principles of Vaishnavism to four disciples: Lakshmi, Brahma, Shiva and Sanatkumara. And they in turn started the four main Sampradayas or traditions of Vaishnavism: Sri Sampradayam, Brahma Sampradayam, Rudra Sampradayam, and Kumara Sampradayam.  Now in [this section](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/antya/2/95) of the ISKCON commentary on the Chaitanya Charitamrita, Srila Prabhupada discusses commentaries on the Brahma Sutras produced by the four Vaishnava Sampradayas:

> The commentary by Śrīla Rāmānujācārya, known as Śrī-bhāṣya, establishes the viśiṣṭādvaita-vāda philosophy. Similarly, in the Brahma-sampradāya, Madhvācārya’s Pūrṇaprajña-bhāṣya establishes śuddha-dvaita-vāda. In the Kumāra-sampradāya, or Nimbārka-sampradāya, Śrī Nimbārka establishes the philosophy of dvaitādvaita-vāda in the Pārijāta-saurabha-bhāṣya. **And in the Viṣṇu-svāmi-sampradāya, or Rudra-sampradāya, which comes from Lord Śiva, Viṣṇu Svāmī has written a commentary called Sarvajñabhāṣya, which establishes śuddhādvaita-vāda.**

Now I'm familiar Ramanujacharya's Sri Bhashya, Madhvacharya's Brahma Sutra Bhashya, and Nimbarkacharya's Vedanta Parijata Saurabha; I've read all three in large part.  But I'm interested in the part in bold.  My question is, did Vishnuswami write a commentary on the Brahma Sutras called the Sarvajna Bhashya?

For those who don't know, Vishnuswami was an ancient Acharya of the Rudra Sampradayam.  Vallabhacharya, the founder of the Pushtimarga sect, is said to have been in the Parampara of Vishnuswami, which is why the Pushtimarga sect traces its origins to the Rudra Sampradyam.  Now I assumed that Vallabhacharya's Anubhashya was the oldest Rudra Sampradayam commentary on the Brahma Sutras, but maybe it's the oldest surviving one.  (I posted a question about surviving Rudra Sampradayam works prior to Vallbhacharya [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18393/36).) Do have any records, like works of Acharyas or modern scholarly works, that mention Vishnuswami's commentary, and if so what is the earliest reference to Vishnuswami's commentary?

By the way, the Dvaita philosopher Narayana Panditacharya said that 21 commentators on the Brahma Sutras preceded Madhvacharya, and he gave a list of them which you can read [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=FVtpFMPMulcC&lpg=PP1&dq=bnk%20sharma%2021%20commentators&pg=PA98#v=onepage&q&f=false).  As you can see, Vishnuswami is not mentioned, unless he's mentioned under a different name.