# What is the Guru Parampara of Suddhadvaita?

Tags: vedanta, pushti-marga, vallabhacharya

Among the [doctrines of Vedanta](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14779/277), I know that Guru Parampara of Advaita (non-dualism) and Vishishtadvaita (qualified non-dualism) as follows:

> नारायणं पद्मभुवं वशिष्ठं शक्तिं च तत्पुत्रं पराशरं च व्यासं शुकं गौडपादं महान्तं गोविन्दयोगीन्द्रं अथास्य शिष्यम्।
>   श्री शंकराचार्यं अथास्य पद्मपादं च हस्तामलकं च शिष्यम् तं तोटकं वार्त्तिककारमन्यान् अस्मद् गुरून् सन्ततमानतोऽस्मि॥
>
> सदाशिव समारम्भां शङ्कराचार्य ​मध्यमाम्।
>   अस्मदाचार्य प्रर्यन्तां वन्दे गुरु परम्पराम् ॥

Advaita Guru Parampara:
SadaSiva/Narayana > Padmabhu (BrahmA) > Vashishtha > Shakti > Parashar > VedVyasa > Shukadeva > Gaudapada > Govinda Bhagvatpada > Adi Shankaracharya.

[Vishishtadvaita Guru Parampara](http://www.ramanuja.org/sv/bhakti/archives/jun95/0041.html):
Vishnu > Laxmi > Vishvaksena > Nammalwar > NathaMuni > Pundarikaksha > Rama Mishra > Yamunacharya > Peria Nambi > Ramanujacjarya

I want to know the Guru Parampara of Suddhadvaita (pure non-dualism), also known as Pushti Marga Vaishnava Sampradaya. I only know that the chief expounder is Vallabhacharya and belongs to Rudra Sampradaya.

Comment: That is not Vishishtadvaita guruparampara, it is Sri Vaishnava guruparampara. Former is a philosophy and latter is faith. Mentioned in Sri Vaishnava guru parampara.

Comment: I will still say the same after the link addition also. It is Sri Vaishnava guru parampara. Author of the article says "Vishishtadvaita Sri Vaishnava"  in the linked article. That too it is a personal article.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma ohk. Btw, is it possible for one to follow Vishishtadvaita without becoming Sri Vaishnava or vice-versa?

Comment: Faith and philosophy are different. One can become Vishishtadviatan without being a Sri Vaishnava but it doesn't work the other way.

Comment: @PrasannaR Observe last two lines of [Avdaita Guruparampara](https://www.advaita-vedanta.org/avhp/advaita-parampara.html); just added in the question body.

Comment: okai got it thanks for taking it easy..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suddhadvaita is based on Vallabhacharya's preaching known as Pushtimarga.He has written commentary on BrahmaSutra called "Anu Bhashya" and expounded the Shuddadvaita Vedanta. This sect is subscribed to [Rudra Sampradaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudra_Sampradaya) of Vaishnavism which is believed to be started from Shiva himself. According to scholars [Vishnuswami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnuswami) was the first who founded the doctrine of Shuddhadvaita by writing commentary on Brahma Sutra called Sarvajñabhāṣya as discussed in [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18944/277).

Following is the Guruparampara of Vishnuswami Sampradaya I found from [Bhaktamal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhaktamal), a poem written in 16th century giving short biography of more than 200 bhaktas. You can read original treatise at [here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.402667/page/n185).

Quoting the Guruparampara of Vishnuswami which is traced back to Shiva from **story of Vishnuswami** and tradition after Vishnuswami from **story of Vallabhacharya** from [Bhaktamal Hindi translation published by Naval Kishor Press in 1884](https://archive.org/details/BhaktamalHindiNavalKishorePress/page/n51): ((Emphasized Vishnuswami and Vallabhacharya in the list))

> 1. शिव (śiva)
> 2. परमानंदमुनि (paramānaṃdamuni)
> 3. आनंदमुनि (ānaṃdamuni)
> 4. प्रकाशमुनि (prakāśamuni)
> 5. श्रिकृष्णमुनि (śrikṛṣṇamuni)
> 6. नारायणमुनि (nārāyaṇamuni)
> 7. जयमुनि (jayamuni)
> 8. श्रिमुनि (śrimuni)
> 9. शंकरभट्ट (śaṃkarabhaṭṭa)
> 10. पद्मभट्ट (padmabhaṭṭa)
> 11. गोपालभट्ट (gopālabhaṭṭa)
> 12. श्रिवरभट्ट (śrivarabhaṭṭa)
> 13. श्यामभट्ट (śyāmabhaṭṭa)
> 14. रामभट्ट (rāmabhaṭṭa)
> 15. सेतभट्ट (setabhaṭṭa)
> 16. कृष्णभट्ट (kṛṣṇabhaṭṭa)
> 17. दिवाकरभट्ट (divākarabhaṭṭa)
> 18. कृपालभट्ट (kṛpālabhaṭṭa)
> 19. विद्याधरभट्ट (vidyādharabhaṭṭa)
> 20. दिनकरभट्ट (dinakarabhaṭṭa)
> 21. मधुनिधानभट्ट (madhunidhānabhaṭṭa)
> 22. ज्ञानदेवभट्ट (jñānadevabhaṭṭa)
> 23. सुरदेवभट्ट (suradevabhaṭṭa)
> 24. शिवदेवभट्ट (śivadevabhaṭṭa)
> 25. शांतभट्ट (śāṃtabhaṭṭa)
> 26. दयालदेव (dayāladeva)
> 27. क्षमादेव (kṣamādeva)
> 28. संतोषदेव (saṃtoṣadeva)
> 29. धीरजलदेव (dhīrajaladeva)
> 30. ध्यानदेव (dhyānadeva)
> 31. विज्ञानदेव (vijñānadeva)
> 32. महाच्चार्य्य (mahāccāryya)
> 33. तत्वाचार्य (tatvācārya)
> 34. नृसिंहाचार्य (nṛsiṃhācārya)
> 35. सुआचार्य (suācārya)
> 36. सुबुद्धाचार्य (subuddhācārya)
> 37. प्रबुद्धाचार्य (prabuddhācārya)
> 38. प्रबोधाचार्य (prabodhācārya)
> 39. असूयाचार्य (asūyācārya)
> 40. रुद्राचार्य (rudrācārya)
> 41. भगवंताचार्य (bhagavaṃtācārya)
> 42. रामेश्वराचार्य (rāmeśvarācārya)
> 43. ब्रह्मविधिचरित्रचार्य (brahmavidhicaritracārya)
> 44. सुदयाचार्य (sudayācārya)
> 45. लक्षमीनारयणआचार्य (lakṣamīnārayaṇaācārya)
> 46. ज्ञानदेव (jñānadeva)
> 47. नामदेव (nāmadeva)
> 48. तिलोचनदेव (tilocanadeva)
> 49. **श्रीविष्णुस्वामी (śrīviṣṇusvāmī)**
> 50. लक्षमणभट्ट (lakṣamaṇabhaṭṭa)
> 51. **वल्लभाचार्य्य (vallabhācāryya)** [Founder of [Pushtimarga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushtimarg)]
> 52. विट्ठलनाथ (viṭṭhalanātha)
> 53. गोकुलनाथ (gokulanātha)
> 54. रघुनाथ (raghunātha)
> 55. यदुनाथ (yadunātha)
> 56. घनश्याम (ghanaśyāma)
> 57. बालकृष्ण (bālakṛṣṇa)
> 58. गोबिन्दस्वरूप (gobindasvarūpa)
> 59. गिरिधरराय (giridhararāya)
> 60. वृंदावनदास (vṛṃdāvanadāsa)
> 61. दामोदरदास (dāmodaradāsa)
> 62. स्वामीशुकदेव (svāmīśukadeva)
> 63. स्वामीहरिचरण (svāmīharicaraṇa)
> 64. स्वामीतुलसीदास (svāmītulasīdāsa)

Comment: Is this Tulasidas is the one whose poems we read in schools?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta No, [Tulsasidas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulsidas), who wrote Ramacharita Manas is another one belong to [Ramandandi Sampradaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanandi_Sampradaya).