# What are the words of the Brahmasambandha Mantra of Pushti Marga?

Tags: vishnu, mantras, vaishnavism, sharanagati, pushti-marga

As I discuss in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10174/36), Vishnu is said to have taught the principles of Vaishnavism to four disciples: Lakshmi, Brahma, Shiva and Sanatkumara. And in turn they started the four main Sampradayas or traditions of Vaishnavism: Sri Sampradayam, Brahma Sampradayam, Rudra Sampradayam, and Kumara Sampradayam. My question is about the Rudra Sampradayam, the one founded by Shiva.  Currently the only Vaishnavas who trace their origins to the Rudra Sampradayam are members of Vallabhacharya's Pushtimarga sect, which worships the Srinathji form of Vishnu (which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2950/36)).

Now like the Sri Vaishnava sect (which I belong to), the Pushtimarga sect believes in the notion of Sharanagati or complete surrender to Vishnu.  But Sri Vaishnava perform Sharanagati using the Dvaya mantra (which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7971/36)), whereas followers of Pushtimarga use a different mantra, the Brahma Sambandha mantra.  The Brahma Sambandha mantra is not found in any scripture, but Vallabhacharya claimed to have learned it from Krishna in a dream.  Here's how Vallabhacharya describes it in his [Siddhanta Rahasya](http://www.pushti-marg.net/siddhant.htm), one of the most important texts of the Pushtimarga sect:

> Here I state, word by word, what the Lord Shri Krshna said to me on the mid-night of the eleventh day of the dark fortnight of the month of Shravan (monsoon season).  By the virtue of being initiated by the "Brahma Sambandha" mantra (sacred mantra, given separately to Shri Acharya), all the sins of the body and the soul are destroyed. Hence, the five obstacles (mentioned in the Vedas and Puranas) to service / "seva" of the divine are also removed.  These obstacles, viz (1) body and it's various states and pure/ impure conditions, (2) your environs, eg country or general state of the area around you (e.g desert, mountains, foreign country etc.) And influence of Kala or "time" ie age, time of day / night etc. (3) Instructions as set by the society at large and the scriptures (Vedas) etc. (4) Influence of your friends and company in general. (5) Impurity incurred by touching impure / inauspicious things. Let none of these stand in your way of service to the Lord.  Apart from Brahma Sambandha (relationship with the Lord), there is no way to destroy one's sins. Hence, discard all things that have not been offered to the Lord.  Those devoted to me, after having taken the Brahma Sambandha, must offer up all their actions and fruits of their deeds un-to me. Lord Shri Krshna, God of all the gods, should never be offered anything that has already been offered to others, or used by others.  Therefore, a devotee must offer everything to the Lord before beginning any project (this includes the "desire to do the work", all the physical objects required to do the work) and also the fruits (success or otherwise) of the work to the Lord. Some sects believe that those things offered up to the Lord are Lord's possessions and can not be used by them. But this is not the view of the Pushti Marga. All things must be offered to the Lord before utilising them yourself.  In a worldly relationship, an employee always seeks guidance and approval of his employer, similarly, always seek guidance and approval of the Lord in all your actions. By offering all your actions un-to Him, your actions will also become as pure and divine like Him.  Like the great Ganges, the Lord purifies all those who come to Him. Muddy / dirty waters of a spring, when they meet the Ganges, are purified by Her divine touch and hence-forth the waters of that spring are given the same respect as the Ganges. Similarly, once a soul merges with the Lord, no matter what his/her previous state, he/she becomes as pure as the Lord Himself.

But my question is, what are the actual words of the Brahmasambandha mantra?  Are there any works by members of the Pushtimarga sect which contain the exact words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the words of the Brahmasambandha Mantra in three books, with minor differences:

1. [This excerpt](http://preview.ibb.co/cFWMna/image.jpg) from Paul Arney's paper "The Bade Shikshapatra: A Vallabhite Guide to the Worship of Krishna’s Divine Images"

   > Om Shri Krishnah Sharanam Mama Sahasraparivatsaramitakalasanjat Krishnaviyogajanitatapakleshananda Tirobhavoham Bhagavate Krishnaya Dehendriyapranantahkaranataddharmamshcha Daragaraputraptavittehpranyatmna Saha Samarpayami Dasoham Krishnatavasmi
2. [This excerpt](https://books.google.com/books/content?id=0vwYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA532&img=1&pgis=1&dq="saha+samarpayami"&sig=ACfU3U23MLUrhgy8KRzJ8x9zADy06VTfvg&edge=0) from Ganga Prasad Upadhyaya's translation of Dayananda Saraswati's Satyartha Prakasha:

   > Shri Krsnah sharanam mama sahasra parivatsaramita kalajat krsna viyogajanita tapa kleshanantatirobhavoham bhagavate Krsnaya dehendriya pranantahkaranataddharmanshcha daragaraputrapta vittehaparanyatmana saha samarpayami daso-aham Krsna tavasmi
3. [This excerpt](https://books.google.com/books/content?id=ziENAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA134&img=1&pgis=1&dq="dllso%27ham+krsna+tavftsmi.1%27+above"&sig=ACfU3U1LtSC6ZRuR9XWiN7qIZV-2aa1x7Q&edge=0) from the introduction of M.T. Telivala's edition of Vallabhacharya's Siddhanta Rahasya:

   > sahasra-parivatsara-mita-kala-jata-krsna-viyoga-janita-tapa-klesananda-tirobhavo'ham bhagavate krsnaya dehendriya-pranantahkaranani taddharmamsca daragara-putrapta-vittehaparani atmana saha samarpayami daso'ham krsna tavasmi

M.T. Telivala seems to have been a member of Vallabhacharya's Pushtimarga sect, so I think his version would probably be the most accurate.  (Except he omits the Pushtimarga ashtakshari mantra that is customarily chanted in the beginning.)

In any case, Paul Arney also provides a translation of the mantra:

> Om. The Lord Krishna is my refuge. For thousands of years and countless eons I have been lost in pain, grief, and sorrow caused by separation from Krishna.  Together with my wife, home, children, elders, and all assets in this world and the next, I  dedicate the functions of my body, senses, life, and soul to the Almighty, Lord Krishna. O Krishna, I am your servant.

Comment: main mantra is "Sri krishah sharanam mama"

Comment: @RakeshJoshi That is the Ashtakshari mantra of the Pushtimarga sect, which is the first mantra taught to new members.  But the Brahmasambandha Mantra is the ultimate mantra that followers of Pushtimarga learn.  That is the one that they believe leads to Moksha.

Comment: Pushtimarg sect does not believe Moksha as destination. Destination is Krishna, the one that is the chief of the Golokdham.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the request of the actual Sanskrit Mantra online but Just to mention, in Pushtimarg sect, this mantra is allowed for recital with certain conditions. 
You can read the meaning but the actual pronunciation/recital of the mantra is to be done only after good bath in the morning after a fast of night. Let's respect someone's belief, especially when investigating about the same.